# Getting users to RSVP to events?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have an app, sort of like meetup.com, users can create events, comment on the events, search the events.. However, I'd like to allow users to click on an 'Attend' button and then on the events/show.html.erb page show which users are attending etc...

Currently a user has_many :events, and an event belongs_to a :user.

So, when a user clicks the event he/she likes they are directed to that events/show.html.erb page. I'd like them to be able to see (X number of people are attending this event) and be able to click that and see who exactly is attending and also be able to click 'Attend Event' themselves.

So how might I do this?

*current event show.html.erb*

```
<%= render 'shared/header' %>                                                                                                                                 

<div class="container">                                                                                                                                       
  <div class="row">                                                                                                                                           
    <div class="span3">                                                                                                                                       
      <%= render 'sidebar' %>                                                                                                                                 
    </div>                                                                                                                                                    
    <div class="span5">                                                                                                                                       
      <div class="new_event_form">                                                                                                                            
        <div class="line1"><h4>Create event</h4></div>                                                                                                        
        <%= form_for current_user.events.new, remote: true do |f| %>                                                                                          
          <h5>Event title:</h5>                                                                                                                               
          <div><%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: "Event title", required: true, autocomplete: :off %></div>                                               
          <h5>Event description:</h5>                                                                                                                         
          <div><%= f.text_area :description, placeholder: "Event description", required: true, autocomplete: :off %></div>                                    
          <h5>Event date:</h5>                                                                                                                                
          <div><%= f.text_field :date  %></div>                                                                                                               
          <h5>Event location:</h5>                                                                                                                            
          <div><%= f.text_field :location, placeholder: "Event location", required: true, autocomplete: :off %></div>                                         
          <div>                                                                                                                                               
            <%= f.submit "Create event", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>                                                                                          
            <%= link_to "Cancel", '#', class: 'btn cancel_event' %>                                                                                           
          </div><br />                                                                                                                                        
        <% end %>                                                                                                                                             
      </div>                                                                                                                                                  
      <div class="events_list">                                                                                                                               
        <!-- look in events/event.hmlt.erb -->                                                                                                                
        <h4><%= @event.title %> at <%= @event.location %></h4>                                                                                                
        <p><%= @event.description %></p>                                                                                                                      
        <h5><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> <%= @event.date.strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y") %></h5>                                                                
        <h5><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <%= @event.time %></h5>                                                                                             
        <h5><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> <%= @event.location %></h5>                                                                                      
      </div>                                                                                                                                                  
      <div class="name"></div>                                                                                                                                

            <%= form_for [@commentable, @comment], remote: true do |f| %> 
...........and so on...
```

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is something wrong with your data model. Your associations are saying that user has many events, but event has only one user. it's `1:N` relation, try change it to `M:N`, with something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_any_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

You will need to provide necessary migrations for the join table, read more about `has_and_belongs_to_many` here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many

Then you will be able to get all users attending specific event simply by calling `event.users` and their count with `event.users.count`.

If you need to keep some more information on the relationship itself, consider using `has_many` with `:through` option. Then the code might go something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendances
  has_many :events, through: :attendances
end

class Attendance 
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendances
  has_many :users, through: :attendances
end

event.users.count # => `3` for example
```

Comment: Thanks so much Kreeki, that is perfect. Would I be able to simply add has_and_belongs_to_many :events to the user.rb and add a event_id column to the user table to get the correct results?

Comment: Sadly, with how relational databases work, no. You will need create an additional table in you database called `events_users` with `user_id` and `event_id` fields (just the table, no model). Then it will work.

Comment: is that technically a has_many :through association then? i.e. a user has_many :events, :through :events_users ?

Comment: Basically yes, with some magic around it. With `has_and_belongs_to_many` you don't need `EventsUser` model, just the table. I will give you an example on how to do it with `has_many :through`.

Answer (score 0):

You should set up a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association between events and users, since an event can have many users, and likewise, a user can "attend" many events.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association